# How can I delete a button on the top right of my home page in Hostinger Elementor?

Tags: button, elementor

The template came with the phone number call button, but it's not my number and I can't edit it. I would like to remove it but I can't figure out how to do it. If you can share some advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to edit the container.